# Do you need to escape data inputs when inserting to Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

Ok, we all know that in traditional SQL databases you have to escape date when inserting to databases, so that their is no SQL injection.  In Cassandra NoSQL databases, is their any problems like that? Do we need to escape any data before we insert into Cassandra?  Any security related things I need to know?

Answer (score 1):

An injection attack is much less of a concern with CQL for a number of reasons.  For one, Cassandra will only execute one complete statement per query so any attack that, for example, attempted to concatenate a `DROP`, `DELETE`, or `INSERT` onto a `SELECT`, would fail.  And, with the exception of `BATCH` (which requires a collection of complete `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` statements), there are no nested queries.

That said, you should *always* sanitize your input, and you should make use of prepared statements, rather than constructing complete query statements in code.